# Passing data with jquery ajax to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

I'm using this code
http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html

and it's works great , I want to add button to let the user change the view from vertical to horizontal

I edited load_data.php and added all the code it's need.

in controller I edited:

```
data: "page="+page,
```

to

```
data: "page="+page+"&view="+1,
```

and added the button(btn_view) in controller but I can't make it work ( change the value from 1 to 2)

and added

```
            $('#btn_view').live('click',{ view: "2" },function(){
            loadData(1);

            });
```

after

```
            $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var pagea = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(pagea != 0 && pagea <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(pagea);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

how to make the button reload the controller  and change view value to 2 in load_data.php

Comment: I don't see your ajax, but to send data through jQuery `.ajax()` it is preferably done like this `data: { foo: "bar" }` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is wrong for sending the ajax data. I've gone to your link and copied the function from that tutorial, and updated with the `view` variable being passed into the ajax `data` properties.

You will pass `view` in as the second parameter, and `loadData` will default that to `1` if nothing is passed in.

```
function loadData(page, view) {

    view = view || 1; // view defaults to 1 if not passed in
    loading_show(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_data.php",
        data: {
            page: page,
            view: view
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                loading_hide();
                $("#container").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });

}
```

So then your view button code looks like this:

```
$('#btn_view').live('click', function(){
    var view = 2;
    var page = 1;
    loadData(page, view);
});
```

I'm not sure what you're doing to determine what `page` is, but I'm guessing from it being hardcoded into that function as `1` that you'll probably need to copy this code into a function:

```
function establishPageAndLoadData(view) {
    view = view || null; // use view if passed in...
    var pagea = parseInt($('.goto').val());
    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
    if(pagea != 0 && pagea <= no_of_pages){
        loadData(pagea, view); // pass view to load function
    } else {
        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
        $('.goto').val("").focus();
        return false;
    }
}

$('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
    establishPageAndLoadData(); // does page under the hood
});
```

So now you've centralized your code selecting the `page` variable, you can use it again in your `view` button. I've added in an optional `view` variable into that function to to use here:

```
$('#btn_view').live('click', function(){
    var view = 2;
    establishPageAndLoadData(view); // calculates page under the hood
});
```

I might be barking up the wrong tree here, but here your controller will always get passed two post variables: `page` and `view`